# область видимости переменой

Tags: php

Есть такая структура сайта

```
<div>           
   <div class="test_1">
      <ul>
         // тут циклом foreach выводятся LI

         $slide_off = $k
      </ul>
 </div>
<?php if ($slide_off > 8) { ?>
<div class="test_2">Какой то функционал</div>               
 <?php } ?>
</div>
```

вопрос как передать в  переменую $slide_off что в условии значение $k.
Через суперглобал не выходит.

Получается из класса test_1 надо передать php значение в test_2 условие которое отображает если число больше 8 скажем будет.

Цикл находится в другом файле и я его инлюд делаю

Comment: Три раза перечитал, но не смог понять, что именно вы хотите и что именно не получается.

Comment: в УЛ находиться инлюд файла где в нем циклом выводятся данные по свои местам. мне надо чтоб в из цикла передать значение в след. теги с классом test_2 где ждет его условие на значение из цикла

Answer (score 0):

Если это все в одном файле то тебе глобальные функции не нужны. А посчитать общее количество элементов можно с помощью [count](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.count.php). А вообще хотелось бы увидеть как реализован сам цикл

Comment: Цикл в другом файле... я его подключаю между UL. Цикл нормальные,  обычный форейч. Проблема в том как заставить увидеть переменную

Comment: @Pavel8289 простым `include`? или в том файле функция

Comment: простым... и в нем цикл с со своий разметкой и т.д.

Comment: В таком случае она и так видна

Comment: Я тоже так думал.. но не видна, всегда ноль показывает

Comment: Сделай под `include`  `var_dump()` и увидишь доступна твоя переменная или нет

Comment: Перед инклудом поставь `$k = 0;` а в самом цикле `$k++;`

Comment: Делал, выводило NULL

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65952/discussion-between-andrii-and-pavel8289).